# Break line on max width text UILabel swift 2

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift2, uilabel

I'm currently trying to make an app that takes the usernames of some people and print them out in a custom cell, inside a label.
But if a user has the name  "John Goodwilkinson" It's a large name,
so i'm trying to figure out how to make a

```
/n
```

Between the 2 words.

Does anyone has any idea?
I've googled but couldnt find anything at all.
Below you can see the screenshots with my code and the suggestions of the fellows :)

[image]

[image]

Also i have tried to put the code in the view controller that i call the custom cell like this

```
 cell.frndName.numberOfLines = 0
 cell.frndName.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
```

But it didn't work either

Comment: Can you post some code about what you have tried? What is the result?

Comment: If you just want to wrap words in label, so you can use: 
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping

Comment: @levantAJ i puted inside the override 'func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        frndImg.layer.cornerRadius = 32
        frndImg.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        frndName.numberOfLines = 2
        frndName.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    }'
because its a custom cell but it doesnt work. any idea?!

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, could you try with frndName.numberOfLines = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by setting the number of lines to the label to be `2` or `0` (if you wnat to be any number) and line breaks to be word wrap.
Link this

[image]

**Update**
after checking you UI. It ended up that removing the height/ width constraints and pinning the label from the bottom/ right the other controllers solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've tried it but it doesnt break the line!

Comment: Would you please share some code / screenshot of the UI, to be able to figure out what's going on?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios it doesn't break because there is no enough height for the label to expand. you need to give the cell more height or **make the height dynamic**. so in the  case the label wants to break to 2 lines it finds enough space.
As you see in the debuging area in your screenshot you have an autolayout problem becuase of the cell height 155.

Comment: i gave the cell more height but still doesn't break the line

Comment: do you have a height constraint to the name label? if yes, please remove it or give it bigger constant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100662/discussion-between-ismail-and-kwnstantinos-natsios).

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase height of your UILabel and apply constant only for its width.

second thing you can add `@“\n”` by `NSString *newUsername = [oldUsername stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@“\n”];`

it will replace all spaces between two words by `@“\n”` and next word will show in next line.

Comment: Why answer in Obj-C when he's using Swift?